# Problema con hibernate java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, hibernate, tomcat

**Al momento de ingresar un dato mediante jsp con hibernate y  mysql me arroja este error :**

> Tipo Informe de Excepción
>
> mensaje La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción
>
> descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no
>   pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
>
> excepción
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una
>   excepción
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   causa raíz
>
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>     controlador.NewHibernateUtil.(NewHibernateUtil.java:29)
>     modelo.OperacionesSoftware.addTipoSw(OperacionesSoftware.java:22)
>     controlador.ServletSw.processRequest(ServletSw.java:40)
>     controlador.ServletSw.doPost(ServletSw.java:75)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   causa raíz
>
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
>     org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:174)
>     org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
>     controlador.NewHibernateUtil.(NewHibernateUtil.java:25)
>     modelo.OperacionesSoftware.addTipoSw(OperacionesSoftware.java:22)
>     controlador.ServletSw.processRequest(ServletSw.java:40)
>     controlador.ServletSw.doPost(ServletSw.java:75)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   causa raíz
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be
>   cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
>     org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildVersionProperty(PropertyFactory.java:181)
>     org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:218)
>     org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
>     org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
>     sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor20.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
>     org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
>     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
>     controlador.NewHibernateUtil.(NewHibernateUtil.java:25)
>     modelo.OperacionesSoftware.addTipoSw(OperacionesSoftware.java:22)
>     controlador.ServletSw.processRequest(ServletSw.java:40)
>     controlador.ServletSw.doPost(ServletSw.java:75)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

**El codigo de el metodo es el siguiente**

```
public void addTipoSw(TipoSoftware sw)
{
    SessionFactory sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sesion.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();



    session.save(sw);

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

**El mapeo de las tabla es :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
  <!-- Generated 12-05-2018 23:47:57 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="modelo.TipoSoftware" table="tipo_software" catalog="mydb" 
 optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="tipo" type="string">
        <column name="tipo" length="45" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="softwares" table="software" inverse="true" lazy="true" 
       fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="tipo_software_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="modelo.Software" />
        </set>
        </class>
         </hibernate-mapping>
```

**La configuracion del hibernate es :**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property 
 name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property 
 name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb? 
 zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">asd</property>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Modelo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Representante.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoSoftware.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Privilegio.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Venta.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Relacion.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Hardware.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoRelacion.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Empresa.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoEmpresa.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoArriendo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoHardware.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Inventario.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/DetalleCompra.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/DetalleArriendo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Ejemplo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/DetalleVenta.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Arriendo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Equipo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Producto.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/DetalleMovimiento.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/RegistroMovimiento.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Compra.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Fabricante.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoEquipo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Cargo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Empleo.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Bodega.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/BitacoraAccion.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Rol.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/TipoMovimiento.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Ciudad.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Pais.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Sucursal.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Usuario.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Estado.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Software.hbm.xml"/>
 <mapping resource="modelo/Bitacora.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
```

**El jsp contiene lo siguiente**

```
<form name="form" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servletSw" method="post">

        <div>
            <label>Ingrese el tipo de software</label>
            <input type="text" name="tipo"/>


        </div>

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>




    </form>
```

La estructura sql de la tabla tipo_software es :

```
CREATE TABLE `tipo_software` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Mi servlet :**

```
    OperacionesSoftware op = new OperacionesSoftware();


    op.addTipoSw(new TipoSoftware(request.getParameter("tipo")));
```

Comment: Camilo, deberías incluir la estructura SQL de la tabla que has mapeado

Comment: la estructura de la tabla tipo de software es esta:   CREATE TABLE `tipo_software` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la espera de que adjuntes lo que te he pedido en el comentario, me atrevería a decir que el problema es que has declarado, a nivel de tabla, la columna *version* de tipo VARCHAR, cuando Hibernate espera que sea un tipo numérico. Fíjate que en la stacktrace tienes el mensaje:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
```

Amplio respuesta a partir de lo que has contestado. Para gestionar el optimistic locking, Hibernate puede usar una columna para guardar un número de versión o para guardar un timestamp (en tu caso, es número de versión). **Ambas opciones requieren que la tabla física tenga una columna del tipo que corresponda** (numérico si es versión o DATETIME si es timestamp).

Por lo tanto, y en resumen, en el mapping de tu entidad TipoSoftware deberías:

```
<version name="version" column="<nombre-column-control-version-hibernate>" type="long" />
```

Si no recuerdo mal, si no añades esa definición, Hibernate busca una columna llamada version.

Eso por un lado. Por otro, en uno de los comentarios indicas que la tabla Software sí tiene un atributo versión de tipo varchar. Entiendo que este campo versión es propio de tu modelo lógico (es decir, es la versión del software, no tiene nada que ver con Hibernate), pero si en el mapping de esa tabla has añadido también el control de optimistic lock, la razón de la excepción que has puesto está ahí. Hibernate busca una columna llamada version, encuentra la tuya, intenta usarla pero, en vez de ser numérica, es un varchar y de ahí la excepción.

Comment: La tabla a la cual deseo ingresar el dato no contiene un campo que se llama  versión.  La tabla software si contiene uno y es varchar y hibernate lo arroja como string.

Comment: Ampliada la respuesta con lo que has indicado.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias me solucionaste totalmente el problema que tenia, era el campo versión que me tiraba la exepción al momento de ingresar el dato, de manera sencilla le cambie le nombre al atributo y se soluciono. gracias te pasaste.

Comment: Perfecto! Sería de agradecer que marcases la respuesta como válida entonces. Gracias! :)